# How to get users mail addresses on OS X Lion?

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-lion

I was getting the users mail addresses from Libraray/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist. They are not there any more in Lion :P Do I have to use scripting bridge? Any hints? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail in Lion stores the equivalent in *~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Accounts.plist*. Note however that you are assuming that the user uses the Apple Mail program, unless that's what you really need you may want to have alternative methods for getting the address. You may for instance depending on how the system has been set up use the CSIdentity APIs, such as CSIdentityGetEmailAddress().

Comment: CSIdentityGetEmailAddress() returns no mail address for me :P Maybe because I have none in my address book...

Comment: I open ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Accounts.plist and if its not there I try the Snow Leopard file. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would get them right out of Address Book.  That should work regardless of what email app is being used.

```
// Find 'me' card in address book.
ABPerson* meCard = [[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] me];
if( meCard == nil ) {
    NSLog( @"Could not find me!" );
    return;
}

// Get my email addresses.
ABMultiValue* anEmailList = [meCard valueForProperty:kABEmailProperty];
if( anEmailList == nil ) {
    NSLog( @"I have no email!" );
    return;
}

// Output them.
for( NSUInteger index = 0; index < [anEmailList count]; index++ ) {
    NSString* aLabel = [anEmailList labelAtIndex:index];
    NSString* aValue = [anEmailList valueAtIndex:index];
    NSLog( @"%@: %@", aLabel, aValue );
}
```

Comment: There are no mail addresses in my 'me' entry. I set up Lion like most people do so I have a fear it does not work like I want it to..

Answer (score 0):

Apple script will get the job done.